# prepareInterstitialAds() deprecated in iOS 10

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Does anyone know how I can call UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds() in iOS 10 because it's deprecated it seems in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iAd has been shut down since July 1.](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/)

Comment: Yes, but I used this to display ads for Google

Comment: What? How? From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1614624-prepareinterstitialads): "Prepares the iAd framework to display interstitial ads, which may involve prefetching ad assets." How would you use that for google ads? O.o' ?

Comment: Oh damn maybe I just havent ever removed the code fully from iAds